# Customize auto-configured Spring Boot Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot, and largely just using the autoconfiguration options for most of the components. However, I have found a few instances where I just want slightly different behaviour from the Beans.

What is the best/suggested approach to doing this?  In many cases I don't want to have to turn off autoconfig just to change one property on the bean, so hoping there is some way I can sensibly update beans properties?

The case I have is the `DispatcherServlet` -  I am happy with the [autoconfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java) but I just want to change my `DispatcherServlet` so the [DispatchOptionsRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html#setDispatchOptionsRequest-boolean-) is set to true.  I am hoping I don't need to turn off autoconfig and copy the configuration locally just to call that setter method?

Comment: FYI: I submitted [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/4300) to make this configurable via properties. It should hopefully be available in Spring Boot 1.3.0 when it comes out.

Answer (score 3):

The dispatcher servlet can be configured by declaring a bean of type `DispatcherServlet` named `dispatcherServlet`, then return an instance configured to your liking. This will override the previous declaration.

Example:

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
    return servlet;
}
```

Comment: Cool - so just by naming any bean the same as the bean defined in the spring autoconfig it will always override it?  Are there any things I should be aware of if I take this approach for other beans? or does spring-boot guarantee this behaviour?

Comment: @rhinds That's pretty much how most of the autoconfiguration works. The Spring Boot reference docs are really worth a read.

Comment: @chrylis I have read most of the docs, but didn't see this point - saw the stuff re: disabling the autoconfig and the various Conditional.. annotations - but neither of these cases relevant here (its quite long though! so probably just missed that point :).  Also, if you see the linked source code for the autoConfig class - the DispatcherServlet bean method is actually used in the initialisation of the another bean (DispatcherServletRegistration) in the same static inner class - will be interesting to see how that can still work with my overriden Bean method?

Comment: It's true for a number of beans, eg the DispatcherServlet, but it is not true of say the CacheManager when using the Spring Cache abstraction. In that case the configuration class should implement a certain interface and the return references from the implemented methods override the default.

Comment: Thanks @zrvan - In this case, looking at the autoconfig source, if I just replace the DispatcherServlet bean I assume the DefaultDispatcherServletCondition will return negative, so that entire inner static class will not be run? In which case I would also need to manually configure the other two beans defined? (which is what I was asking if I could avoid :)